# html menu change drop down text color only

Tags: html, css, navigation, blogger

I'm trying to change the color of the text on only the part of the menu that drops down. My problem when changing the font color is it changes the font color for the whole menu rather than just the drop down part of the navigation.

i apologize in advance its been years since i worked with html and i'm very rusty.

[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIuX2.jpg)

The code here:

```
<div style="text-align: left;">

<style>


#homelink {
background-image: url(http://i946.photobucket.com/albums/ad301/campbellmichelle41109/sims3_logo_ver931034_zpsmnyi2tcj.png);
background-repeat:  no-repeat;

background-color: transparent;
display: block;
width: 126px;
height: 140px;
}

#homelink {
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: -97px;
}



#mbt-menu, #mbt-menu ul {
margin: -15px;
padding: 17px;
list-style: none;
}
#mbt-menu {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
javascript:void(0)
background-image: url("http://i946.photobucket.com/albums/ad301/campbellmichelle41109/navbg1.1_zps86kuvvkj.png") repeat-x;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;

 }
 #mbt-menu:before,
 #mbt-menu:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 }
 #mbt-menu:after {
 clear: both;
 }
 #mbt-menu {
 zoom:1;
 }

 #mbt-menu li {
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid #328ad4;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #469ee8;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #469ee8;
 box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #469ee8;
 position: relative;
 }

 #mbt-menu a {
 float: left;
 padding: 10px 25px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
 }

 #mbt-menu li:hover > a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 *html #mbt-menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
 color: #000000;
 }

 #mbt-menu ul {
 margin: 20px 0 0 0;
 _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
 opaciaty: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 46px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 9999;
 background: #ffffff;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 }

#mbt-menu li:hover > ul {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
margin: 0;
}

#mbt-menu ul ul {
top: 0;
left: 150px;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
_margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

#mbt-menu ul li {
float: none;
display: block;
border: 0;
_line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #227ac4, 0 2px 0 #666;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #227ac4, 0 2px 0 #666;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #227ac4, 0 2px 0 #666;
}

#mbt-menu ul li:last-child {
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}

#mbt-menu ul a {
padding: 7px;
width: 130px;
_height: 9px; /*IE6 only*/
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
text-transform: none;
}

#mbt-menu ul a{
font-size: 12px;
font-color: #000000;
}

#mbt-menu ul a:hover {
background-color: #ffffff;
}
#mbt-menu ul li:first-child > a {
-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#mbt-menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 40px;
top: -6px;
border-left: 6px solid transparent;
border-right: 6px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 6px solid #469ee8;
}

#mbt-menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
left: -6px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -6px;
border-left: 0;
border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
border-top: 6px solid transparent;
border-right: 6px solid #3b3b3b;
}

#mbt-menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
border-bottom-color: #04acec;
}

#mbt-menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
border-right-color: #0299d3;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

#mbt-menu ul li:last-child > a {
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

</style>

<div align=center>

<ul id="mbt-menu"> 
<li><a id=homelink href="http://sims3addictresource.blogspot.com/"></a></li> 



<li> 
<a href="#">Simology</a> 

<ul> 
<li><a href="http://sims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/needs.html">Needs</a> </li> 

<li><a href="http://sims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/skills.html">Skills</a></li> 

<li><a href="http://sims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/traits.html">Traits</a></li> 

<li><a href="http://sims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/moodlets.html">Moodlets</a></li> 

<li><a href="http://sims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/lifetime-wishes.html">Lifetime Wishes</a></li>

<li><a href="http://sims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/lifetime-rewards.html">Life Time Rewards</a></li>

<li><a href="http://sims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/death.html">Death</a> </li> 

<li><a href="http://sims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/ghosts.html">Ghosts</a></li>
</ul> 
</li> 


<li> 
<a href="#">Expansion Guide</a> 

<ul> 
 <li><a href="#">Ambitions</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Generations</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Pets</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Late Night</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Supernatural</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">World Adventures</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">University Life</a></li>
</ul> 
  </li> 


<li> 
<a href="#">Towns</a> 

  <ul> 
  <li><a href="#">Sunset Valley</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Monte Vista</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Hidden Springs</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Dragon Valley</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Roaring Heights</a></li> 
  </ul> 

</li> 

<li>
<a href="#">Free Downloads</a>

     <ul>
     <li><a href="#"> Custom Sims </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sliders</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>


<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 

</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#mbt-menu a {
float: left;
padding: 10px 25px;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-transform: uppercase;
font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
```

This part of the css is the one that is causing the issue. You are setting *any* link that is part of the menu to be white, even the ones that are not the submenu.

You can instead move that `color: #ffffff` out, and do

```
#mbt-menu li ul a{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

This finds all the `a` tags that are part of the menu that are under a sublist and sets the color to white.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#mbt-menu li ul li > a {
    color: // your colour here;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to fix that

```
#mbt-menu ul a {
   color:coral; //change any color here
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vqhtyqb5/2/)